# Using minimal ubuntu as type 1 Hypervisor, viz-a-viz oVirt?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, hyper-v, ovirt

Though i found "minimal Ubuntu", but nowhere did i find the "Ubuntu Hypervisor" like oVirt, with just the essentials.

**What will it take** to build a type-1 hypervisor, a lean-mean-fighting machine with GUI management features and all desired features for a top class hypervisor from "Minimal Ubuntu"?

Has anyone done that before? (I guess many).

Thanks.
RJ

Comment: "Minimal" Ubuntu is still an OS, so you are talking a Type 2 hypervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**oVirt Node** is not just a minimal CentOS, it's made upon squashfs and imgbased for smart installation, upgrade and rollback.

I suggest you to read the [oVirt Node Next Development Guide](https://ovirt.gitbooks.io/ovirt-node-next-development-guide/) to better understand its design.

Comment: Thanks, but i was concerned that it has no plans for container support. Also, not sure how it fares against minimal-ubuntu+openstack (which i think it would turn it into a full ESXi type host). Also, I am reading th elink you gave, it is good read. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see, most of the upcoming enterprise projects are focusing on K8s-oriented platforms (OpenShift, Pivotal) as opposed to legacy platforms that added containers support (OpenStack, vSphere, Proxmox).

Therefore, container support is not part of the oVirt roadmap. Rather, the team is working hard to add the new oVirt Cloud Provider based on Terraform for both [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) and [OpenShift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/welcome/index.html).

Comment: oVirt Node is the data-center virtualization open source project nearest to ESXi architecture. In the other hand, OpenStack is a cloud IaaS capable of compute, network and storage abstraction (mainly). Please do not confuse virtualization platforms with cloud platforms only because oVirt and OpenStack both relies on KVM.

Comment: Thank you, Stefano. I was thinking both to be same. I am still confused how virtualization platforms with cloud platforms are different and which product is which. Do you have any good link to book/article for that? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to read [What's the difference between cloud and virtualization?](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/cloud-computing/cloud-vs-virtualization)